# Get name of text that automatically generated by button onclick script function

Tags: javascript, php, html

This code is for generating a `textbox` in my button `onclick` function. I want to get the name value of each text box in `php` code.

```
<script language="javascript">
        var i = 1;
        function changeIt()
        {            
            my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='mytext'+ i>"
            i++;
        }
        </script>
```

HTML code:

```
<p>
<input type="button" value="test" onClick="changeIt();"></p>
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. What are you tried?

Comment: $('#my_div').text($('#my_div').text() + " "+insertText);

Comment: @Bugfixer "in php code" not javascript.

Comment: that means you want all input type=text value as array??

Answer (score 0):

You need to first fix you JS to output the name values correctly with the incremented values.

```
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='mytext"+i+"'>"
```

The HTML should be wrapped in a `<form>` element so that we can send the form values to a php document to process using the 'get' method. I have also added a submit button so that we can submit the form.

```
<form action="process.php" method="get">
    <input type="button" value="test" onClick="changeIt();">
    <div id="my_div">
    </div>
    <input type='submit' value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then on the PHP document we can iterate over the form names using a while loop and push each value to an array called `$textboxes`

```
<?php 
    $textboxes = array();

    $i = 1; 

    while(isset($_GET[ "mytext".$i ])) {
        array_push($textboxes, $_GET[ "mytext".$i ] );
        $i++;
    } 

    var_dump($textboxes); 
?>
```